# FileReader local image path

Tags: javascript, image, local, filereader

My app is not web based so there is no server to grab images from, it's a local app that incorporates an embedded IE. As a part of this within the javascript I'm trying to grab some images from my local drive without using the text input and upload button of course since it will be part of the GUI. I've spent the past couple of hours trying different things but can't seem to get FileReader to read my local image and put it in my . Is this not possible? Can someone show me please?

Comment: You're embedding IE. Why not just add the stuff you need on the local app side? You can have javascript methods that will be handled in your application, and you can call those from your JS code.

Comment: The images will vary depending on the circumstance and be part of a function being called often. I want it run strictly in the javascript environment in order to not interrupt or delay the other functions being run in the app natively...so things run parallel or hyperthreded of sorts.

Comment: Well, you'll get the javascript method calls on the UI thread. Surely, the UI thread is doing nothing 99% of the time?